# Failed reallocation assignment

Tags: c, arrays, realloc

My program is a command line database program. It's a mini. You can create an entity inside database. Command is like "CREATE ENTITY name". And I have a problem in creating entity function.

I reallocate memory for my struct array. Just I am expanding. But after second expansion, I am losing character array of second element(ankara) of expanded array. Let's look at the code;

```
void task_create_entity(char* name)
{
int status;
ENTITY *e = create_entity(name, &status);
if(e)
{
    if(db->entities == NULL)
    {
        db->entities = new_entity_list(4);
        db->list_size = 4;
        db->entities[0] = e;
        db->size = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int old_list_size = db->list_size;
        if(db->size >= db->list_size)
        {
            ENTITY **temp = expand_entity_list(db->entities, &db->list_size);
            if(temp != NULL)
            {
                if(db->entities != temp)
                    db->entities = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Operating system did not allocate memory, entities list could not expanded\n");
                drop_entity(e);
                db->list_size = old_list_size;
                return;
            }
        }
        db->entities[db->size++] = e;
    }
    task_list_entities();
}
else
{
    if(status == 1)
    {
        printf("Already exists a entity in database with this name\n");
    }
    else if(status == 2)
    {
        printf("Entity file could not created\n");
    }
}
}
```

This function creates entity and appends array which in DB(struct). If array size is small, my function expands it and appends it. I am printing my entities name with `task_list_entities()` function, after I created new entity. Console inputs and outputs are:

```
CREATE ENTITY istanbul
istanbul

CREATE ENTITY ankara
istanbul
ankara

CREATE ENTITY seul
istanbul
ankara
seul

CREATE ENTITY monako
istanbul
ankara
seul
monako

CREATE ENTITY manchester
istanbul
ankara
seul
monako
manchester

CREATE ENTITY paris
istanbul
ankara
seul
monako
manchester
paris

CREATE ENTITY lizbon
istanbul
ºÖW
seul
monako
manchester
paris
lizbon
```

List starts with 4 element and expands as 4, 6, 9, 13, ... This is code of expansion:

```
ENTITY** expand_entity_list(ENTITY** entities, uint32_t* size)
{
    *size = *size + (*size / 2);
    return (ENTITY**) realloc(entities, *size);
}
```

After second expansion operation, I am losing name of second entity(ankara).

```
ENTITY* create_entity(char* name, int* status)
{
    ENTITY *entity = (ENTITY*) malloc(sizeof(ENTITY));
    entity->file = NULL;
    entity->name = duplicate_string(name);
    entity->records = NULL;
    entity->size = 0;
    entity->commited = 0;
    *status = 0;
    return entity;
}
```

This is new entity list function:

```
ENTITY** new_entity_list(uint32_t size)
{
    return (ENTITY**) malloc(sizeof(ENTITY*) * size);
}
```

and this is string duplication function:

```
char* duplicate_string(char* origin)
{
    char *dup = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(origin) + 1));
    strcpy(dup, origin);
    return dup;
}
```

As a result I couldn't find the cause of the error. Other value of entity are not lost. Just char* name. This is entity struct:

```
typedef struct entity
{
    char *name;
    FILE *file;
    RECORD **records;
    int size;
    uint8_t commited;
} ENTITY;
```

Comment: Some important parts are missing from your question - eg. how are `new_entity_list` and `duplicate_string` implemented ? Please create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I tried detailing. I am getting a segmentation fault error on my next access because I lost the address of the char array after expanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ENTITY** expand_entity_list(ENTITY** entities, uint32_t* size)
{
    *size = *size + (*size / 2);
    return (ENTITY**) realloc(entities, *size);
}
```

Is `*size` in bytes or in entities? You seem to assume you can store `*size` pointers in `entities`, but you only allocate `*size` characters. I doubt pointers are one byte on your platform!

You probably want:

```
    return (ENTITY**) realloc(entities, *size * sizeof(ENTITY*));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I overlooked.